# Linker error in Iar

Tags: stm32, st, iar

When I compiled a program using stm32l476 micro controller using IAR embedded workbench IDE, I am getting the following linker error.
Error[Li005]: no definition for "rtt_seq" [referenced from C:\Users\Documents\new project\EWARM\new project\Obj\uipmain.o]

Comment: In your code, there's at least one call to a function/method named `rtt_seq()`. But there's no definition of this function in your code. Could be an absence of the required header file(s).

Comment: Since it is a linker error, the code compiles fine and correct headers may be included, but there is no function rtt_seq() anywhere the linker could find. Are there any compilation warninga that might indicate about rtt_seq() ?

Comment: RTT in this context is probably referring to Segger's "Real Time Transfer" which allows for sending & receiving data to/from your micro while debugging - things like maybe a terminal window or getting/setting the contents of registers, etc. You must have enabled this feature in your IAR project settings somewhere, so I'd suggest that you search through your project properties & settings for something labelled with "RTT" and disable whatever you find.

Comment: there is no compilation warnings except for some other function declarations. I checked the header files included. But, it keep giving me the above mentioned error.

Comment: *"there is no compilation warnings" - This only indicates that the header files for *rtt_seq* are present but the definition (implementation) is missing. Possible reasons: (1) The .c/.cpp file with the *rtt_seq* implementation is not part of the project (and was not complied). (2) *rtt_seq* is part of a library and the library is not part of the project. (3) *rtt_seq* should not have been used in the first place.

Comment: Please invest some time in additional investigations regarding what *rtt_seq* is and where it is used. After all you are the only person with access to the project and code. The error message says that *rtt_seq* is used in *uipmain.o*. Does your project contain a file *uipmain.c* or similar? Does it contain a reference to *rtt_seq*? Does any of the header files included directly or indirectly delcare *rtt_seq*?

Comment: @Nileena160 See if your linker can produce a detailed output file that includes a memory map among other things. Also, just a note regarding the comments here. A linker can issue a "no definition" error for constants and variables, as well as functions. (I can provide detailed examples of all three cases.) The filename you show includes "new project" as part of it and this suggests to me that uipmain is one of your own files and not a library source/object. So you should be able to string search your source files for 'rtt_seq'. Can't you?